# How do I get vim to not ask for confirmation interaction?

Tags: docker, go, vim, terminal, dockerfile

If I run the following command inside a Dockerfile:

```
vim -c "GoUpdateBinaries"
```

It works, but ultimately gets stuck building with:

```
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I avoid that?

I tried:

```
RUN vim -c "execute 'GoUpdateBinaries' | execute 'redraw'"
```

That worked when trying it from my terminal, but not from the Dockerfile and building a new image as it introduced `--more--` on the screen (not sure why?) which I then couldn't side step either

Comment: I think `:silent` will help... from help, `:silent will also avoid the hit-enter prompt`

Comment: I remember to have used `call feedkeys(' ')` for similar cases, maybe it can help

Comment: If you're just updating some Go tools, why not update them directly rather than through vim/vim-go?

Comment: The list of go binaries is determined by the vim plugin Vim-Go. Also the GoUpdateBinaries command only works in vim context and I didn't want to manage that list and behaviour separate from the plugin

Answer (score 0):

So I found a solution...

```
RUN vim -c "execute 'silent GoUpdateBinaries' | execute 'quit'"
```

Not sure if that's the ideal solution or if there is something easier?

What's annoying about this solution is:

A. the `silent` means you can't see your progress with the installed binaries

B. you still see an instance of vim actually start up (which is kinda weird)